# Odd operator precedence/associativity behaviour

Tags: python, python-2.7, operator-precedence

How is it that, in Python 2.7, the following

```
True == 'w' in 'what!?'
```

behaves differently than both

```
(True == 'w') in 'what!?'
```

and

```
True == ('w' in 'what!?')
```

?

```
>>> True == 'w' in 'what!?'
False

>>> (True == 'w') in 'what!?'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bool

>>> True == ('w' in 'what!?')
True
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python, comparisons can be [chained together](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

So your code is actually equivalent to

```
>>> (True == 'w') and ('w' in 'what!?')
False
```

Comment: Oh wow, `in` is subject to chaining?! Who'd have thought? (+1)

Comment: Yeah, it's a little surprising because it doesn't look like most other comparison operators, which are predominantly not expressed using letters. But `in` and `is` are full-fledged `comp_operator`s, just like "<" and ">" and "==", etc :-)

Comment: I would have guessed about `is`, but `in` is... unexpected. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse("""True == 'w' in 'what!?'""", mode='eval'))
"Expression(body=Compare(left=Name(id='True', ctx=Load()), ops=[Eq(), In()],
comparators=[Str(s='w'), Str(s='what!?')]))"
```

This is a [chained comparison](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once [...]